# Operating on multiple strings to produce a string

Tags: string, emacs, character

With `result` set to `("cypueihajytotrdkgzxfqplbwn" . "cypueihajytomrdkgzxfqplbwn")` the below code gives the desired result of knocking out the mismatching character "t": 
`"cypueihajytordkgzxfqplbwn"`

Without the `concat` the result is returned as a list of ints, representing the ASCII values of each char in the string.  But the inputs themselves are regarded by evaluator as strings.  So I'm losing the stringyness of the `result` within the algorithm (probably because `mapcar*` treats each string as a list of chars, and chars are just ints).

My question is - is there an idiomatic way to maintain the stringyness of a variable rather than having to re-enforce it at the end by using `concat` or `apply #'string`.  IMHO the `concat` makes the code a bit noisy(er).

```lisp
(print (concat (mapcar #'car (cl-remove-if-not 
        (lambda (r) (equal (car r) (cdr r)))
        (mapcar* #'cons (car result) (cdr result))))))
```

Comment: It's not about differentiating a string from a list of chars. And variables do not have data types in Lisp - instead, values have types. Your variable `result` starts with a value of type list (of two strings), and you want it to end with a value that has type string. That has nothing to do with a supposed "stringiness" of the variable itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary data type in Emacs Lisp is list. Emacs provides many functions (such as `car` and `cdr`) to process list, and it's easier to deal with list than array (including vector and string). For example, the function `mapcar` returns a list even you pass a string or vector to it:

```lisp
(mapcar #'identity "hello")
;; => (104 101 108 108 111)

(mapcar #'identity [1 2 3])
;; => (1 2 3)
```

It's not uncommon to convert array into list, process the list, then convert back to array. Besides `concat` and `string`, you can also build a string with `mapconcat`.

For your code, you're using mapcar-like function three times, the following uses just one time, I think it's easier to read

```
(let ((result (cons "cypueihajytotrdkgzxfqplbwn"
                    "cypueihajytomrdkgzxfqplbwn")))
  (concat
   (delq
    nil
    (cl-mapcar
     (lambda (c1 c2) (and (= c1 c2) c1))
     (car result) (cdr result)))))
;; => "cypueihajytordkgzxfqplbwn"
```

With an imperative approach, the code is even more cleaner

```
(let ((result (cons "cypueihajytotrdkgzxfqplbwn"
                    "cypueihajytomrdkgzxfqplbwn")))
  (cl-loop for x across (car result)
           for y across (cdr result)
           when (= x y)
           concat (string x)))
;; => "cypueihajytordkgzxfqplbwn"
```

Comment: Really useful - one quick follow-up I note you're using `=` function for comparison of each character.  If chars are ints is it more correct to use `eq`?

Comment: @Phil Both are correct. Chars are ints, and I prefer `=` to check if two numbers are the same. And `(= a b)` will signal an error if `a` or `b` isn't a number, `(eq a b)` will never fail, so when you are sure `a` and `b` can only be numbers, `=` provides more protection.